# AngularJS data model architecture

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, datamodel

I have the following thing on my Angular app:

```
$scope.things = [{
   title: 'Simple',
   type: 1,
   form: {
         input: [1, 2, 3],                        
         clone: true
      }
}];

$scope.clone = function(item) {
   item.form.input.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 999));
};
```

And on the HTML part:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in things" class="item">
   <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
   <div ng-repeat="input in item.form.input">
       <input type="text" />
   </div>
   <button ng-click="cloneInput(item)">Clone</button>
</div>
```

When press the *Clone* button I'm pushing a new element to form.input array and add a new input to the DOM.

I want to $http.post all the values for the inputs.

I know to push something I need to use

```
$http.post('/path/to/my/api', {my object}).callback()
```

But I dont know how to make an object from all the **.item** inputs.

Can someone explain me how or suggest a better solution?

Comment: It really depends on how your backend accepts the data. In front-end, you have the array then you are able to format it as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `ng-model` for your inputs and set it to an object you can then inject that object to the post, here is a really basic example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/xd7715m3/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div ng-repeat="input in items">
        <input type="text" name="{{input.name}}" ng-model="data[input.name]" />
    </div>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
    <p ng-show="displayIt">{{data}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        name: 'test'
    }, {
        name: 'test2'
    }];

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.displayIt = false;
    $scope.submit = function () {
        // This is only to check it
        $scope.displayIt = true;
        // Do your post here
    };

}]);
```